# Login with post request and xsrf token but getting a 419

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests, csrf

I am trying to login to slicethepie.com using pythons requests library.

From my understanding, I am getting a 419 because I am not passing a csrf token. The only similar token I see in Chromes network tab is an XSRF-TOKEN. **Do I need to pass that instead? Why is my code returning a 419?**

You can currently see I am passing the XSRF token in the cookie but no luck.

```
import requests

link = "https://www.slicethepie.com/login"
response = requests.get(link)  # no XSRF token in here

payload = { "email": "newtalent0909@gmail.com", "password": "password", "_token": "w4uj7bk4KRjheHk05MajnrWfHyS9PmN7mmMgUpx5", "validation": "token", location[latitude]: None, location[longitude]: None}

headers = {
    "Cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=...tokenInImage...slicethepie_session=...tokenInImage...",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer": "https://www.slicethepie.com/login",
    "Origin": "https://www.slicethepie.com",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(
        "https://www.slicethepie.com/login",
        headers=headers,
        json=payload,
    )
    print(p) # returns 419. Page Expired
```

[image]

Form Data in Payload

```
_token: w4uj7bk4KRjheHk05MajnrWfHyS9PmN7mmMgUpx5
_token: w4uj7bk4KRjheHk05MajnrWfHyS9PmN7mmMgUpx5
validation: token
location[latitude]: None
location[longitude]: None
email: newtalent0909@gmail.com
password: password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following  code is tested and works fine:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

link = "https://www.slicethepie.com/login"

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(link)  # no XSRF token in here

token_value = bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select_one('form input[name="_token"]').get('value')
payload = { "email": "newtalent0909@gmail.com", "password": "password", "_token": token_value, 'location[latitude]': None, 'location[longitude]': None}

headers = {
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer": "https://www.slicethepie.com/login",
    "Origin": "https://www.slicethepie.com"
}
s.headers.update(headers)
p = s.post("https://www.slicethepie.com/login",data=payload)
print(p)
print('_________________________________________')
print(bs(p.text, 'html.parser').text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
<Response [200]>
_________________________________________

















What would you like to review? on local
 - Slice the pie











My account

Profile
Balance
Reviews
Email preferences
Change password
Close account



Notifications






                View older
            



Your balance is $0.00





Lifetime totals



0
reviews



0
friends



 
totals






                        Make a withdrawal
                    

                View transaction history
            



Star rating



This is a measure of the quality of your reviews, the more Stars you have the more you'll earn!














Review










Refer a friend

















$0.00


Privacy policy


FAQ


Terms and conditions


Contact us


About us


Log out









                    What would you like to review?
                

                    Select a category
                





Unfortunately we are unable to accept reviews from your location at this time. We will email you when the site becomes available to you.









FAQ
Privacy policy
Terms and conditions
About us





















© Shisho Data ltd 2023
```

Requests documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), and for BeautifulSoup documentation, go [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: congratulations my friend 

Answer (score 1):

Since [@BarrythePlatipus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19475185/barry-the-platipus) objected that my previous answer is similar to his/her, I am providing an alternative response to this question!

I think,instead of using the `json` parameter in your `post` method, it's better to use the `data` parameter to send the payload as form data, because it can be done by converting the payload dictionary to a string using `urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)`!

something like this:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

link = "https://www.slicethepie.com/login"
response = requests.get(link)  #no XSRF token in here

payload = {
    "email": "newtalent0909@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "_token": "w4uj7bk4KRjheHk05MajnrWfHyS9PmN7mmMgUpx5",
    "validation": "token",
    "location[latitude]": None,
    "location[longitude]": None,
}

headers = {
    "Cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=...tokenInImage...slicethepie_session=...tokenInImage...",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer": "https://www.slicethepie.com/login",
    "Origin": "https://www.slicethepie.com",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    p = s.post(
        "https://www.slicethepie.com/login",
        headers=headers,
        data=payload_str,
    )
    print(p)  #check response code & content
```

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I apologize for not having read your response earlier, and this was the answer that I thought was appropriate. However, out of respect for the fact that you responded earlier, I will provide another method to answer this question, or if I cannot find another method, I will delete it!

Comment: @MouseWarrior if the method of BarrythePlatipus didn't work for you, please take a look at my previous method too, It might give you a good perspective!